# How to set canvas in div with center align of screen

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have 3 div(Div 1, Div 2, Div 3) and also canvas which is in div. So I want to set `#canvasDiv` in Div 2. I have tried it but `#canvasDiv` id sleep down and Div 1 & Div 3 is placed upper side.

I want set all div in one line which is canvas div should be in Div 2(center).

Please see the fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/8mm2bc2b/2/

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your HTML markup is incorrect. The space is already occupied by the above div and canvas div is not wrapped inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following way: Use `vertical-align:top` for `div1` and `div3` so it will not go down. And put canvas div inside div2.

```css
#canvasDiv {
     width: 300px;
     height:200px;
     margin: 0px auto;
   }
```

```html
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <div style="border:1px solid #000; display:inline-block;height:200px; vertical-align: top;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;height:200px; width:300px;">Div 2
    <div id="canvasDiv"  >
<canvas id="myCanvas"    style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas> 
</div>
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red; display:inline-block;height:200px;vertical-align: top;">Div 3</div>
</div>
<br/>
```

Check [Fiddle Here.](https://jsfiddle.net/8mm2bc2b/7/)